# Returning a temporary argument in C++: Identity function

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

In C++, I can write a statement `std::string& x = f();`.  If `f()` returns a `std::string` (not a reference), it will extend the lifespan of the temporary variable until `x` goes out of scope.

What if I wanted to write something like `std::string& x = identity(f());`, where `identity` should "pass through" the value.  Is there a way to do so which can extend the lifespan of the temporary value returned by `f()` just like it did in the simpler case?

I'm willing to overload `identity` as needed to support the different kinds of references if needed, but the rules for lifespan extension were always tricky, so I'm not sure if it can be done.

Comment: when `f` returns a `std::string` then `std::string& x = f();` is a compiler error.

Comment: *In C++, I can write a statement std::string& x = f();. If f() returns a std::string (not a reference), it will extend the lifespan of the temporary variable until x goes out of scope.* That is 100% incorrect.  You can only bind a temporary to an rvalue reference (`T&&`) or a const one (`const T &`)

Comment: what is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Tell us about that rather than only about the code you want to use to get there

Comment: Why not just capture a `std::string` result like the function returns? There's no need for a reference.

Comment: `std::string& x = f()` shouldn't compile if `f()` returns by value. You may be using Visual Studio which provides an extension that allows it, but this is not allowed by the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In C++, I can write a statement std::string& x = f();. If f() returns a std::string (not a reference), it will extend the lifespan of the temporary variable until x goes out of scope.

No, the program would be ill-formed and the compiler should fail to compile it or at least provide some diagnostic.

If you had used `const std::string&` or `std::string&&` instead, then you would be correct.

> What if I wanted to write something like std::string& x = identity(f());, where identity should "pass through" the value. Is there a way to do so which can extend the lifespan of the temporary value returned by f() just like it did in the simpler case?

No, it will never extend the lifetime of the temporary past the full-expression. It is impossible to extend lifetime through *any* function call.

The reason is that generally C++ is designed in such a way that a compiler is only required to consider the declaration of a function, not its body/definition, while compiling a call to it, even if an optimizing compiler with optimizations enabled will generally still do so if it sees a definition in the same translation unit or link time optimization is enabled. Calls to `constexpr` functions in (potential) constant expressions and functions requiring return type deduction are somewhat exceptions.

So you can't rely on knowing how `identity` will forward the reference. But the caller would need to know that if it was supposed to extend the lifetime of the temporary which was created in its context and for which it is responsible.

Comment: If identity just returns by value an instance moved from its argument, then it sort of works to the extent the original did. It doesn't seem very useful though.